# Python, matching items in 2 lists

Tags: python

I have 2 lists that have the equal amount of integers inside

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
```

I want to match the items in numerical order. So I want a result like

```
C = [4,1,5,2,6,3]
```

Is it possible to create a function that returns a value like this ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: "I want to match the items in numerical order." What does this mean? More examples or descriptions may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` to make this

```py
def merge_lists(list_a, list_b):
  merged = []
  for pair in zip(list_a, list_b)
    merged.extend(pair)
  return merged
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, just use `zip` like so:

```
res = []
for pair in zip(B,A):
    res.extend(pair)
```

*Note that this assumes the lists are the same length

Comment: Simpler: `[x for xs in zip(b, a) for x in xs]`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you're right, but a nested comprehension is not a good way to teach a newbie

Comment: Although this doesn't produce the asker's  result. It would if you just swap places on `A` and `B`, but the statement _"I  want to match the items in numerical order"_ seems to suggest some comparison the pair, like taking the larger one first.

Comment: That's how we do the `flatMap` in python

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.chain` to join the zipped tuples.

```py
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

print(list(chain(*zip(b, a))))
```

Comment: Another way of `flatMap` in python.

Answer (score 0):

Folks are often too quick to resort to loops or external libraries. Neither is needed here.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]

C = list(sum(zip(B,A),()))

print(C)
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]
```